# find value in multiset and erase if exists

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, std, multiset

I have code like this:

```
// implementation of multiset
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variale
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>


using namespace std;

class Rect{
public:
        double height;
        double width;
        double area;
        string name;

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Rect& r);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Rect& r)
{
    os << r.area << " " << r.name;
    return os;
}

struct LessArea
{
    bool operator ()(const Rect& lhs, const Rect& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.area < rhs.area;
    }
};

std::multiset<Rect, LessArea> rects;
```

I am producing data (in a thread but probably not relevant). Before I insert the new `Rect`, I would like to search the `multiset` and if the `Rect` with that name exist, `delete` it. Then add new one:

```
produceData()
{
  const string arrayString[4] = {"C", "B", "N", "A"};
  int RandIndex = rand() % 4; //generates a random number between 0 and 3
  string name = arrayString[RandIndex];

  int randomNumber1 = (int)(rand() % 1000);
  int randomNumber2 = (int)(rand() % 1000);
  int randomNumber3 = (int)(rand() % 1000);

  Rect value = {randomNumber1, randomNumber2, randomNumber3, name};

  // I would like to delete a rect if the name already exists regardless of other values
  rects.erase(s.lower_bound(value)); // This won't work because it is matching ALL fields


  // Add new value
  addToMultiSet(value);
}
```

How do I `search` the `multiset` and delete the element if the `name` is already contained?

**EDIT 1**

```
class Rect{
public:
        double height;
        double width;
        double area;
        string name;

        bool operator == ( const Rect & rhs ) const { return ( name == rhs.name ); }
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Rect& r);
};

...

multiset<Rect>::iterator ceItr = rects.find( value );

if(ceItr != rects.end())
{
    rects.erase(ceItr);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove an item with the same name but different other values or the same name with the same other values? Shouldn't the area be calculated from the width and height versus a random number that has no relation to them?

Comment: I don't care what the other values are. If name is already in multiset, remove it.

Comment: Then you'll need to iterate through the entire set and remove items that match the name.

Comment: This needs to be super fast as it is a realtime application. Is there a way to hash the multiset index of a name? The multiset is guaranteed to ever only have one of a name

Comment: _"This needs to be super fast as it is a realtime application"_ -- you're using a `multiset` already, those aren't exactly known for efficiency. You will always have a large amount of cache-misses thanks to all the pointer-chasing. Just out of curiosity, why is this a `multiset` at all? If names are unique, a `set` using the name as a key be easier for removal. You can always have a separate data-structure like a vector that maintains iterators into the set to keep the order by area, if that matters. The indirection from iterators would be the same as walking the `multiset` range.

Comment: This multiset is ordered by `area`. That's the only way to look up the multiset. The only way to identify all values in the multiset with a particular `name` is to iterate over ***alll*** values in the multiset. If that's not acceptable then an additional lookup method must be implemented, using an additional lookup container, with care taken to make sure that the data remains consistent.

Comment: got it humancompiler

Comment: Sam, see Edit 1. That doesn't seem to work?

Comment: `rects.find( value )` uses the comparator to find an equivalent value. Since your comparator doesn't use the name it isn't relevant to the search, only an item with a matching area would be found.

Comment: Which part of "This multiset is ordered by `area`, that's the only way to look up the multiset" you have a question about?

Comment: got it. Ugh. I need to sort by area, but need to search by name

Comment: Correct. A multiset is always looked up by whatever its key is, and it is ordered by the key.

Comment: This surely can be reduced down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - It currently isn't one.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear to me. When you find a `Rect` object with the same name, do you intend to **delete** it, or is doing an **update** sufficent for your purpose? Also, it seems that you are fighting with a data-structure that is designed for a single key, which in your case is the area of a `Rect` object, and you want to have a second-level key by the `name` field of a `Rect` object. I think you should explore something like Boost multiindex and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Do you need fast lookup by name AND the ability to iterate over the rects sorted by area? If you just need fast name lookup, unsorted_map<name, Rect>? Or you could have both, referencing the same object, and for fast delete, just set a flag on the rect telling it to not print (and cleanup later)?